# How to change the forward direction of Raycast

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object in my unity3d project.

Somehow its face is facing unity's down.
So if I Raycast to forward, the ray is actually pointing to object's up.
If I Raycast to down, the ray points to object's forward.

How to correct this?

Here is the code:

```
function Update () 
{

    //scan
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.down);
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, fwd, hit, 50)) 
    {
       var distance = hit.distance;

       print('distance = ' + distance);
    }
    else
    {
        print('Raycast did not hit anything');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. It might have been confusing.

Comment: So you want to raycast in the forward direction of the object, but your code doesn't use transform.forward. Why?

Comment: I might be missing something but isn't the solution to set the object straight so it's face points forward like it should?

Comment: I just noticed in unity3d there is a global, a local and a 3-colors-arrow. Now, I select the object, then I switch between global and local. I can see this 3-colors-arrow changing. When I switch to global the green arrow points this way. When I switch to local the green arrow points that way.

Now, this green arrow must represent one of the sides of the object (left/right/front/back).

Is that correct?

Comment: I imported this object from blender. I made it in blender, then I export it into .obj, then import the .obj into unity3d project. Maybe the object position in blender affecting the 3-colors-arrow position when exported into .obj.

Comment: @HappyApple, because when I Raycast with Vector3.forward, it cast ray to object's upward. I think this has to do with the 3-colors-arrow position (example: green arrows points to which direction) of the object. The object's forward face does not agree/sync with the 3-colors-arrow's forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to change the local rotation of your object to point in the direction you want. I believe that the blue arrow represents the forward direction. :)

Comment: casper, yes I have re-oriented the object using blender so that when imported into unity the object's face is facing where the blue arrow points.